# Getting ST_Difference between two different tables in postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

One table has a series of grid squares in it, and the other has millions of voronoi polygons in it. I need to create a table that has the difference between the two of the them so that I effectively get the **holes in the voronoi layer**.

I've tried several things like this:

```
SELECT st_astext(ST_Difference(density_squares.geom, 
       st_collect(density_squares_voronoi.geom))) As new_geom    
FROM density_squares_voronoi left JOIN density_squares ON
       ST_Intersects(density_squares.geom,density_squares_voronoi.geom)
group by 
       density_squares.geom;
```

But I get one output gridsquare for every voronoi polygon instead of the one cropped polygon like I need. Will I need to union the voronoi layer first or something?

---

I had to crack on and get it finished, so I just wrote some .net code to run it as a batch process. However I'm now trying to union the data and that is also taking a long time. A screen shot is here of what it looks like

[image]

and the sql i'm trying to use is this:

```
Select st_union(density_square_islands.islands) 
into density_square_islands_union 
from density_square_islands 
where st_touches(density_square_islands.islands,density_square_islands.islands)
```

You can see the individual squares within the cropped islands. I just need to union the squares within each island into a single polygons

Comment: ST_Intersect first - http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html do you have a screen shot of your current output

Comment: could you give me an example or pseudocode about how to use intersect first? Only I did try something like this but the output was still seperate versions of the main polygon each with a single voronoi cut out. its like I want to crop single geometry against whole table, but the functions want to crop each geometry against each geometry, hence the duplication.

Comment: You haven't explained your problem clearly enough to solve it. As Mapperz notes, a simple picture of your inputs and desired output would go a long way towards that.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not uploading picture. I couldn't figure out how to do it. Its ok I had to crack on and get it finished, so I just wrote some .net code to run it as a batch process. However I'm now trying to union the data and that is also taking a long time. A screen shot is here of what it looks like [IMG]http://i46.tinypic.com/2ut6kqc.png[/IMG] and the sql i'm trying to use is this: Select st_union(density_square_islands.islands) into density_square_islands_union from density_square_islands where st_touches(density_square_islands.islands,density_square_islands.islands); thanks

Comment: that url might not work: try this http://tinypic.com/r/2ut6kqc/6      You can see the individual sqaures within the cropped islands. I just need to union the squares within each island into a single polygons